# Kann man sagen "es ist nicht darauf bezogen"?

Tags: word-usage

Im Sinne von "es hat damit nichts zu tun".

Kann man so sagen wie im Titel steht, oder muss man anders den Satz sagen wie z.B. "es bezieht sich nicht darauf".

Danke

Answer (score 2):

*Es ist nicht **da**rauf bezogen.* ist grammatisch richtig. Wenn du das so sagen willst, betone das *da*. Ansonsten klingt es seltsam.

Besser ist aber *Darauf bezieht es sich nicht.*

Comment: Danke, herr Janka.